# Does amdgpu kernel driver require non-free firmware to be loaded?

Tags: gpu, firmware, amd-graphics

Its good to see Amd supporting open source community by releasing source for amdgpu linux kernel driver.

But does this open source amdgpu driver require non-free firmware to be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The open source drivers do use AMD's proprietary blobs yes...

(This is why you have to install the firmware-linux-nonfree package, otherwise the code would be in the kernel).

I'm using the opensource AMDGPU driver along with the closed firmware. This is compiled into the kernel with "CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE". You can use opensource all the way, this will send generic instructions to the firmware, which would be unstable and suboptimal.

The same applies to nvidia with: gk20a  gm200  gm204  gm206  gm20b  gp100  tegra124  tegra210...

Not to mention there will be microcode on the device itself.

An interesting topic raised at linuxcon 2015 was that the closed firmware of a usb controller exploited could reek havok... This is were there is a push for open hardware, I think alot of this surfaced alot faster as a result of some bios exploits.

here is a snippet from the license (for the closed firmware):

Copyright (C) 2009-2016  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. All rights reserved.

REDISTRIBUTION: Permission is hereby granted, free of any license fees,
to any person obtaining a copy of this microcode (the "Software"), to
install, reproduce, copy and distribute copies, in binary form only, of
the Software and to permit persons to whom the Software is provided to
do the same, provided that the following conditions are met:

No reverse engineering, decompilation, or disassembly of this Software
is permitted.

Answer (score -1):

By default during your Linux installation, the O.S should be loaded with the free AMD drivers.... (for eg. the `mesa` driver, or the `Ati-Xorg` driver)...

These drivers are fairly good for Normal graphics / GPU usage.The Open source driver can work independently.

In fact, if you need to install the proprietary drivers like the fglrx driver or the driver package you can download for your specific model from ATI website, you will have to uninstall the free drivers because they are in conflict..

I recommend you install the non-free drivers only if:

1. You use a laptop with AMD graphics card and face overheating issues.
2. You would be using applications that require extensive GPU power.
3. You would be using a Linux distribution not based on Gnome. (In my personal experience, the non-free drivers do not go well with Gnome; however, they perform super awesome with Unity and Cinnamon as the default Desktop Manager.)

Comment: Please be noted that I'm not asking about proprietary drivers (which we have choice to use open source drivers most of the time). I'm asking about the non-free binary firmware used by different hardware. Specifically I'm asking about the `firmware-linux-nonfree` package used by debian/ubuntu (or analogous non-free firmware packages).